# How to make inferior shell inherit environment variable?

Tags: shell, environment

I would like to set the environment variables defined within Emacs available to inferior shells launched afterwards.

My use-case is to be able to switch Python (conda) environment within Emacs.

If I do:

```lisp
(setenv "CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV" "py_39")
```

and launch an inferior shell with `C-u M-x shell`and type `echo $CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV`, I still have `base`.

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17451828/2476009), `setenv` should set environment variables for the inferior shell launched afterwards. It does not work for me.

FWIW: I am running `Emacs 30.0.50`

Comment: Works for me, on a just-built Emacs with the same version (I didn't realize that the version was bumped).

Comment: Probably a shell initialization file is invoked that sets the `CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV` variable after Emacs launches the shell. Try setting a nonsense variable (unlikely to be found in one of your shell init files): `(setenv "FOO" "BAR1234")` launch an inferior shell and check: I bet it will work. So find the place in your shell init file(s) that sets `CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV`: if it is in your `.bashrc` (or equivalent), then move it to the appropriate `.profile` file. Your `.bashrc` is sourced when you start *any* interactive shell, so it probably clobbers the setting in your Emacs environment.

Comment: you are right ! The problem is due to `~/.zshrc` and some code ran by `conda` when the shell got initialised

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by [@NickD](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/14825/nickd) [in a comment above](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/74857/how-to-make-inferior-shell-inherit-environment-variable/74872#comment122220_74857) the environment variable is correctly set but is then unset by the shell init script (~/.zshrc in my case).